# question about coldfusion displaying query result in a cfgrid

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfgrid

i have a coldfusion cfc and some methods in it. MethodA will return a cfquery object. now i use cfajaxproxy to call MethodA and get the query result in a cfm page. this cfm page already have a cfgrid there. now my question is how can i display the query result getting from MethodA in the grid which already have data display in it?

Comment: Can you please show the code? Typically cfgrid data populated using own "bind" attribute, where you define the CFC method invokation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use cfgrid bind="cfc:You.CFC.Path.method(x,y,z,zz)", and you may want to use [QueryConvertForGrid()](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#QueryConvertForGrid) in CF to prepare the data required for cfgrid.

see "Dynamically filling form data" for reference: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/ajaxui_5.html